# Is there a way to ignore javascript comments when deserializing BSON objects using the MongoDB C# Driver?

Tags: c#, javascript, mongodb

I have a POCO object that is serialized using myObject.ToJson() using the BsonExtensionMethod included in the MongoDB C# Driver.  I am taking this string and appending some javascript comments with a textual description and some metadata before persisting it to disk as a .js file.

The object looks like this:

```
{
  // MyObject created 2014-08-18
  "name" : "MyObject",
  "description" : "Super Cool Object"
}
```

When I try to deserialize the object using

```
var myObject = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(json);
```

I get the error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileFormatException' occurred in MongoDB.Bson.dll

Additional information: JSON reader was expecting a name but found '//'.
```

Is there a way to ignore the javascript comments without manually removing them first?  It seems like this should be the default behavior.

NOTE: When I serialize the object using ToJson(), I am also passing in a JsonWriterSettings that inserts line returns, specifies the indent, etc.

Comment: comments are **not** valid JSON

Comment: According to Douglas Crockford, "JSON does not have comments. A JSON encoder MUST NOT output comments.  A JSON decoder MAY accept and ignore comments." https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/json/conversations/topics/152  I'm hoping that the MongoDB C# Driver would allow this and strip out any comments before parsing.

Comment: BSON does not have comments so trying to deserialize JSON with comments into BSON won't work. You can [open up a ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP) requesting comment stripping in the driver if you like, but I think a good solution would be to put comments in a comment field, which should be easy to remove.